# How to convert dict to string in concatenation?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, merge

I have python dictionary class that is generated from API call returning below result

{'url': 'https://propertypro.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/4249.json', 
'id': 4249, 
'external_id': None}

{'url': 'https://propertypro.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/4089.json', 
'id': 4089, 
'external_id': None}

the code as follow;

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests

credentials = 'some email', 'some password'
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = credentials

params = {
    'query': 'type:ticket tags:test_python',
    'sort_order': 'asc'
}

url = 'https://propertypro.zendesk.com/api/v2/search.json?' + urlencode(params)
response = session.get(url)
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Status:', response.status_code,
          'Problem with the request. Exiting.')
    exit()

# Print the subject of each ticket in the results
data = response.json()
```

I iterate the data in order to get all values from key 'id' to be assigned to variable `id_merged` as String with comma separated

```
for result in data['results']:
    # Ticket to update
    id_merged = (result['id'])
```

but get only one result instead of 2, the var gets overwritten in the loop?

```
from test_search import data
import json
import requests

# Iterate the search result
for result in data['results']:
    # Ticket to update
    id_merged = (result['id'])

print("**Start**")
print(id)
body = 'Test ticket'

# Package the data in a dictionary matching the expected JSON
data_comment = {'ticket': {'comment': {'body': body}}}

# Encode the data to create a JSON payload
payload = json.dumps(data_comment)

# Set the request parameters
url = 'https://propertypro.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/update_many.json?' + \
    'ids=' + str(id_merged)
user = 'some email'
pwd = 'some password'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

# Do the HTTP put request
response = requests.put(url, data=payload,
                        auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers)

# Check for HTTP codes other than 200
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Status:', response.status_code,
          'Problem with the request. Exiting.')
    exit()

# Report success
print('Successfully added comment to ticket #{}'.format(id))
```

I'd like to get a result like `'https://propertypro.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/update_many.json?' + \
    'ids=' + 4249,4089` .

How do I get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to turn the values of `id` into a comma delimited string, you can do the following.

```
','.join(id.values())
```

So change your code to

```
url = 'str,' + 'str1:' + ','.join(id.values())
```

For completeness, if you wanted to do the same thing with the dictionary keys, you'd just use

```
','.join(id)
```

Comment: Hi Deepstop, tried your suggestion

`url = 'https://propertypro.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/update_many.json?' + 'ids=' + ','.join(id.values())`

but get this error 



`4249
<class 'dict'>
4089
<class 'dict'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "put_comment.py", line 17, in <module>
    'ids=' + ','.join(id.values())
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found`

What I did wrong here?

Comment: I didn't make a copy of your original post, and now you've changed what I wrote no longer applies. It seems you've figured out how to use `join` now, though, and `chain_from_iterables`, and you've removed `url = 'str,' + 'str1:' + ` so the question you are asking no longer seems to match your revised code. So what is your question and what line are you getting the error on?

Comment: Hi, after checking back my code, I actually need to assign new variable by using loop but it will overwrites the value and I could only get result from the last iteration, this is my exact question now, how to assign dict to new var using loop and turn it to string comma separated value?

Comment: `id_merged = [result['id'] for result in data['results']` will create a list containing the values of the `id` field for each dictionary that is an element of the list `data`.

Comment: Hi Deepstop, thank you for your help! I'm now able to get the value I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are getting list of list in dict values, in that case you can flatten the list and join on string "," like:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> ",".join(map(str, list(itertools.chain(*[[1,2,3],[4,5]]))))
'1,2,3,4,5'
```

Comment: Hi Sagar, updated my entire code and follow your suggestion
`url = 'https://propertypro.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/update_many.json?' + \
    'ids=' + ','.join(chain.from_iterable(data))`

but it didnt throw any success
`4249
<class 'dict'>
4089
<class 'dict'>
Status: 400 Problem with the request. Exiting.`

Comment: Plz check your request, HTTP Status `400` means `Bad request`. Check your input json.